# Why the SQL Team introduced SET ANSI_NULLS ON

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I read an interesting article [here](http://ranjithk.com/2010/01/10/understanding-set-quoted_identifier-onoff/)

It tells that when `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` is written, the SQL Server behaves comparison of the NULL values in a different way. The examples given in the website is as follows:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON IF NULL = NULL  PRINT 'same' ELSE  PRINT 'different'
 --result:  different

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON IF NULL IS NULL  PRINT 'same' ELSE  PRINT 'different'
 -- result: same
```

While I can understand the text, I cannot understand `why did the SQL have to behave this way ?`

1. Why can't we just use the `=`. What is the intention behind it ? Why are we forced to use `IS NULL` kind of syntax ?
2. In future versions of `sql server`, it seems that the `set ansi-nulls on` is going to be default.

There is surely a reason behind it. Any one can explain this to me ?

According to @Blams' answer, I tried below code. Still same results no matter we set `ansi nulls to on or off`.

```
create table A
(
id int identity not null,
name varchar null
)

create table B
(
id int identity not null,
name varchar null
)

insert into A (name) values ('a')
insert into B (name) values ('b')
insert into A (name) values (null)
insert into B (name) values (null)

set ansi_nulls off
select A.name, B.name from A join B on A.name = B.name

set ansi_nulls on
select A.name, B.name from A join B on A.name = B.name
```

Result Set:
 --None--

Both seems to be returning empty rows. If I do a `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, it should compare `null=null` and return true, Correct ? Then why no results are returned?

Comment: The question of why almost any expression with null results in null is easy: consider null to be "unknown", and you'll see (eg. `unknown = something` is unknown because what else could it be?). Why SQL Server has an option: in these questions the usual answer is compatibility with applications that depend on that behaviour.

Comment: My answer did not say = would work that way in a join.  I said I pretty but much never want a match on null in a join.  Take up product behavior with Microsoft.  There are existing answers on SO on how to get a match on null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use = then just  SET ANSI_NULLS OFF.

If I am doing a join on a.name = b.name I would pretty much never want a match on null.

Comment: Kindly see the edit above. Still something is not quite right  :(